# Visual Studio for Mac not finding Telerik nuget packages

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget-package

I cloned a Xamarin project to the mac machine, but I keep getting build errors that the package of Telerik.Ui.For.Xamarin.(PackageName) could not be found. No packages exist with this id in sources.

Now the thing is, it only lists DevExpress and Nuget but not my telerik source?

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new source of nuget packages (URL: https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json) what is showed step by step [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/installation-and-deployment/telerik-nuget-server#visual-studio-for-mac) in the official page of telerik.

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

[image: Finally]

"After the Telerik NuGet server is added you will be able to see the available for download packages in the Manage NuGet Packages... dialog. This will allow you to check the Telerik UI for Xamarin pack and add it into your projects."

[image: nuget]

Comment: This has been done, but it seems as if it only sees Nuget and devexpress and not the Telerik source.